# Approach for unsupervised time series clustering/segmentation

Tags: time-series, unsupervised-learning

I have a big sample of data on a human's everyday life. The snapshots of the life are taken every 5 minutes. The data include time, the location of the human, accelerometer data, gyroscope data, and others.

The data are unlabeled and I know that there have to be 5 main clusters: "sleeping", "eating", "exercising", and "working"...

Before I made assumptions, e.g., "if human's location is x and if the accelerometer value is y and gyroscope value is z, duration is k, then human is sleeping". I know this may create issues as sometimes there may be a different label for those precise values. Therefore, I thought of using time-series clustering for my problem.

How do I approach it? Or am I complicating the solution and I should simply use my "if var1 value = x, var2 value = x2, then the label is N"?

As I mentioned, the data are not labeled, but I know there should be 5 labels.

I appreciate your help to put me on track.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a dimensional reduction algorithm such as [t-SNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) or [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), in order to visualize the different clusters in an unsupervised way.

This is quite easy to do, as long as you normalize the data first in the case of t-SNE.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

dataset = your_dataset

#(here you normalize each column with their max)

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, n_iter=5000, random_state=3)
points = tsne.fit_transform(your_dataset[features])
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
```

Once you have detected the ranges of values from each cluster, you should be able to define which is sleeping, running, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What if I also care about the duration of the event? Let's say if it looks like the human is sleeping, but the duration was only 5 min, I know that is false (I assume there were no 5 min naps).